# Dependency Injection

Tags: object-oriented, php

I read somewhere that it is better to pass an object into the constructor rather than instantiating it in it.

So instead of

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->user = new User();
    // more stuff...
}
```

I should do

```
public function __construct($user) {
    $this->user = $user;
    // more stuff...
}
```

But then what ends up happening is something like this:

```
$user = new User();

// generate routes...

$router->get('/article', function() use ($user)) {

    $page = new Views\ArticlePage($user);
    // more stuff...
}
```

And my question is what happens when code like the above is nested, and we are injecting much more dependencies. The code ends up being harder to understand.

```
$router->get('/article', function() use ($router, $db, $user, $request, $and, $more, $stuff, $needed)) {

    $page = new Views\ArticlePage($view , $db, $user);
    // do more things....
}
```

What is a remedy to that? Or when does it become ok to create new objects ( If it's ever the case)

Comment: If parameters become a lot - you can always wrap them by one class which have properties as your parameters.

Comment: If your class have too much parameters, then class have too much dependencies, which is a sign that your design goes wrong.

Comment: Start writing unit tests and you will see that classes, which creates another classes (which have some functions, not only data) by `new` is a real pain from testing point of view

Comment: For complex object graphs you usually want to go the way of some dependency iniection container.

Comment: Anyways, DI containers aside, methods with so many parameters tends to harm maintainability and as stated by Fabio, It's sign of poor design. Before creational patterns or DI, would be good to review the actual design.

Comment: Specifically, a large number of dependencies is a hint that your class or method is violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for that is [creational patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern).

You are free to use every tool in your language to make construction easier. Construction doesn't have to be flat procedural code in main. You can use factories, builders, parameter objects, and more.

You can create objects that have default values only so long as you provide ways to override them.

You can create objects that hold the typical defaults and expose as dependencies parameters that have no good default values. You can even create a set of objects that hold different defaults within them.

What you shouldn't do is mix construction and behavior. Just hard coding without any way to override means you might as well not even be using classes. Procedural code would be easier to read and be about as flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the work can be done automatically by Dependency Injection. Just a short example based on your code:

```
use DI;
use View\ArticlePage;

public function getPage() {
    $page = DI::get(ArticlePage::class);
    // do things
    return $page;
}

class ArticlePage {

    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

As in your example, `ArticlePage` needs as `User` to be instantiated. Here, instead of creating `User` yourself, DI will create a `User` for you. Having type hint in the `ArticlePage` constructor is part of the DI magic in creating the object.

The same thing would also happen in `User` object creation, most likely it needs something like a `Session` object. DI will create the `Session` when it needs to create `User`.

This is just one of Creational Patterns. In the case of, where you know what are the dependencies of an object, I think it's the most useful.